How to change the background color of a cell (range) by providing RGB values in another cell
I am looking for a way to change the bacground color of a cell by providing RGB values in another cell.
Sample RGB Table

It looks like a custom script will be requried.  I found this reference another post:
How to change the color of a cell based on RGB data in other cells on Google Sheets
but it only allow to change the color of one cell. (and I do not know enough about scripts to expand the function to cover a range myself).
I am looking for a similar function that can be called in a cell formula, or a function that monitors a column and changes the background color of the cells based on the RGB values on another cell.
Any ideas?

The documentation describes perfectly how to expand the range over more than one cell. Did you try to implement that? If so please show us what you did so we can tell where you went wrong. Some effort on your side is expected. Stack overflow is not a free code writing service.

Here is a quick proposal to address this request using the previous solution with some small changes. The code below will work adaptively and insert the background colour in the next adjacent cell.
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // Change the name of the sheet if required
  const row = e.range.getRow()
  const col = e.range.getColumn()
  const cell = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue()

  let cellinput = cell.split(',')
  const cellinput2 = cellinput.map((ele)=> (Number(ele)))
  const cell2 = sheet.getRange(row, col + 1)

  cell2.setBackgroundRGB(...cellinput2);
}

